# The way to use custom method everywhere without requiring the module everywhere

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js. I defined a custom method to the String obj like this:

```
if (!String.prototype.myMethod) {
    String.prototype.myMethod= function () {
         //do something 
        return this;
    };
}
```

I found that `myMethod` maybe used in many different files, so that I have to require the file where this piece of code in. Is there any way that does the many 'requires' ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Node is intentionally designed in a module pattern, where each module gets it's own scope to run in and without polluting the global variables. This very intentional and very important.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper